# How to arbitrarily change the string and the number of each entry of a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

`\cftchaptername` can be used to set a string right behind the title of a chapter. However, once one sets it in the preamble, it is repeated for all chapters. But, how can one arbitrarily change the aforesaid string and its corresponding number, independently, from one entry to another having? In particular, the following `MWE`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter }

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{His Chapter}
    \chapter{Her Book}
\end{document}
```

yields a table of content like

```
Chapter 1 His Chapter
Chapter 2 Her Book.
```

Instead, how can I get

```
Chapter 1 His Chapter
Book 1    Her Book
```

?

Comment: First, do you really want to rename `\section`?

Comment: You can add a new entry with `\addcontentsline`, renumber chapters by changing the values of the counters `section`, `chapter`, etc., and give entries a different name in the table of contents through the optional argument `\section[Name in ToC]{Name in Title}`, etc.

Comment: @Davislor: I don't want to rename `\section`s. In this example, the second section is called `Her Book` in both cases. I just want to change the text and the number before the section title. As you said, the number can be changed by the playing with counters. Yet I'm not sure how I can handle the text part.